# Char* pointers and char[]

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm working on learning pointers in C++, and was doing fine with int*, double*, etc. but then I tried something that I can't understand. I've attached my code segment, and the comments are the terminal output.

```
char word[] = "Hello there";
    cout << word << endl; //Hello there
    cout << *word << endl; //H
    cout << &word << endl; //Address

    char *wordpt = word;
    cout << wordpt << endl; //Hello there
    cout << *wordpt << endl; //H
    cout << &wordpt << endl; //Address

    wordpt = &word[0];
    cout << wordpt << endl; //Hello there
    cout << *wordpt << endl; //H
    cout << &wordpt << endl; //Address
```

What's going on in these? I don't even understand how the `contents of word` (`*word`) can be a single index. How is `word` stored in memory? And why would `wordpt` allow me to give it a value of `word`, which isn't an address?

Comment: Didn't know about array decaying. Sorry everyone. Marking as solved when the timer finishes counting to 5 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer `wordpt` in the first case points to the first element of the array `word`, the second assignment is exactly the same thing but explicitly.

Arrays are automatically converted to pointers to their first elements as is specified by the c standard which also applies to c++.

What is confusing you is the fact that `cout` automatically prints the contents of a `char *` pointer instead of the address the pointer points to, to do it there is a requirement, the pointed to data must be a c string, i.e. a sequence of non-`nul` bytes followed by a `nul` byte, which is what is stored in `word`.

So `cout` is accessing the data pointed to by the `wordpt` pointer.